# WebFlux Concurrency Model in Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

After upgrading from Spring-Boot 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 I have noticed that request processing thread names have changed. Also, it looks like there are now more threads dedicated to HTTP request processing. After some experimantation I can see that on a 4-core server we have now:

- reactor-http-server-epoll-* - 4 threads handling incoming HTTP requests.
- reactor-http-client-epoll-* - 4 threads handling responses from the WebCLient
- reactor-http-nio-* - 4 idle threads

With Spring Boot 2.0.1 I remember having only 4 reactor-http-nio-* threads which took charge of processing both incoming requests and WebClients responses - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-concurrency-model.

- Are my findings valid?
- What is the reason behind this change?
- What is the job of reactor-http-nio-* threads now?

Comment: Have you already found out?

Comment: No, I have not.